# AES 256 bit encryption in pdf file

Tags: c++, encryption, pdf-generation, itext

I am working on PDF Security and trying to encrypt User and Owner password using `AES 256-bit encryption` algo.

I have generated these keys successfully (using `crypto` library) but when these keys are written in `PDF` Encryption dictionary they do not seem to work. (`Acrobat` does not open the file)

I have explored `iTextSharp` which does the encryption of `pdf` file. Now I want to decrypt that file so that some how I get the idea how `iTextSharp` has done it. But unfortunately I did not find any tool to do so. The file encrypted using `iTextSharp` is correctly opened in `Adobe Acrobat`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the password isn't "encrypted" but is instead "stretched", a small but important detail. Also, writing the keys to the dictionary is only a small portion of the process, you need to actually encrypt things, too. If you are interested in this process, you can [download the iText source](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/). I start with `itext/kernel/pdf/PdfReader.cs` and `itext/kernel/pdf/PdfEncryption.cs`

Comment: There are too many moving pieces for you to say "encryption does not work, what's wrong". We need to hear more about the details. We also need to see what you did with your implementation. I seem to recall PDF encryption uses MD5 to digest the password and RC4 to encrypt the document. Also see one of the PDF references at [Adobe PDF Reference Archives](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive.html). For example, [Adobe Portable Document Format Version 1.4](http://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/PDFReference.pdf), page 78.

Answer (score 0):

while encrypting keys you have to use SASLprep
(IETF RFC 4013) profile of stringprep (IETF RFC 3454). The thing i want to add is lib ICU can generate  SASLprep (IETF RFC 4013) profile easily.